# Extract http://www.website.com from http://www.website.com/08/2010/super-cool-article

Tags: php, regex, extract

I suck at regex, I only managed to get so far `preg_match("/http:\/\//", $url)`.

I need this for a php script

Comment: +1 Don't worry about finding them tough - as the old quote goes:   Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$parts = parse_url('hotpotatoes://asd.com');
return $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'];
```

Comment: parse_url ftw. But you shouldn't have mentioned hot potatoes. That's quite harsh of you. No i have to stop work and go get some. If I lose my job for this, I'm gonna find you!

Answer (score 1):

Or by using regex:

```
<?php
$blah="http://www.website.com/08/2010/super-cool-article";
preg_match('/^http:\/\/(\w|\.)*/i',$blah,$matches);
$result=$matches[0];
echo $result;
?>
```

or by an explosion:

```
<?php
$blah="http://www.website.com/08/2010/super-cool-article";
$blah=explode("/",$blah);
$result=$blah[0]."//".$blah[2];
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative expression would be `/^http:\/\/[^\/]++/`.
`++` is used because a possessive quantifier is more efficient.

```
preg_match("/^http:\/\/[^\/]++/", 
           "http://www.website.com/08/2010/super-cool-article", 
           $matches);
echo($matches[0]); // "http://www.website.com"
```